# You cannot use a Stripe token more than once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I cannot seem to charge a card then create a customer on the fly in Rails 4.

```
def charge
 token = params[:stripeToken] # can only be used once.
 begin
  charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => 5000,
    :currency => "gbp",
    :source => token,
    :description => "Example charge"
  )
 rescue Stripe::CardError => e
  # The card has been declined
 end

 if current_user.stripeid == nil
  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(card: token, ...)
  current_user.stripeid = customer.id
  current_user.save
 end
end
```

[I have looked at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334678/how-to-create-both-a-customer-and-a-card-in-a-single-action-with-stripe) but there is no such thing as `token.id` as `token` is just a `String`.

Comment: And you're not submitting the token (i.e. creating a charge) anywhere in your JS code?

Comment: I'm using Checkout.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the token in two locations:

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
    :amount => 5000,
    :currency => "gbp",
    :source => token,
    :description => "Example charge"
  )
```

And also here:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(card: token, ...)
```

In fact, creating a Stripe charge from a token should also create a customer along with the card, if it didn't already exist. Your step of creating a customer is unnecessary. Therefore, just fetch the Stripe customer from the source:

```
current_user.update_attribute(:stripeid, charge.source.customer)
```

Relevant Stripe documentation:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/ruby#create_charge

**EDIT**

If you want to have more control over the charge process, create each object independently:

```
customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
  description: "Example customer",
  email: current_user.email
)

card = customer.sources.create(
  source: "<stripe token>"
  customer: customer.id
)

Stripe::Charge.create(
  amount: 5000,
  currency: "gbp",
  source: card.id,
  customer: customer.id
)
```

Comment: Cool but are you saying I do not need a stripe customer? I got this `undefined method id for nil` from `customer.id`)

Comment: Odd, it's not nil for me. Are you using the latest Stripe API?

Comment: No. Let me update and see. But I must have a stripe customer to keep track of their spending.

Comment: Then create the customer, card, and charge in separate steps. See my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Yeah that's it really. I must have a stripe customer if none is present. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way to get customer details by providing stripeID? I'm using PHP server as backend.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49999506/didcreatepaymentresult-stripeid-is-a-card-token-cant-seem-to-save-to-customer