# didCreatePaymentResult stripeID is a card_ token, can't seem to save to customer

Tags: php, ios, swift, stripe-payments

I have a swift iOS app which asks the user to their payment details for a payment in app and future payment. This uses the stripe SDK with Apple Pay and seems to all be set up correctly.

I have the below method:

```
func paymentContext(_ paymentContext: STPPaymentContext, didCreatePaymentResult paymentResult: STPPaymentResult, completion: @escaping STPErrorBlock) {
    orderToken = paymentResult.source.stripeID
    StripePaymentClient.setupAccount(token: orderToken)
}
```

With then the setupAccount method sending the `orderToken` to my backend PHP server. Which has code like:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                 'source'   => $_POST["orderToken"],
                 'email' => $user["Email"],
                 'description' => "Name: " . $user["FirstName"] . " " . $user["LastName"]
            ));
```

Now the problem is the above PHP gives an error (token obscured):

> No such token: card_XXXXXXXXXXX

I assume this is because the PHP Stripe method is expecting a card toke in the form tok_ and not card_

How do I either use the card_ token and save it against a customer. Or how do I get a tok_ token from the stripe API within iOS. Neither methods seem clear from the documentation or my research.

Comment: me too have the same issue with PHP backend.